# I can't read and then write the data in the same text file

Tags: java

In this code i am searching for a string in a file named source and if it doesn't exist i have to write the string in the same file(source). When I run this code the whole program doesn't respond. When I don't read from the file and directly write the program works. What am i doing wrong?

```
if(addChoice.getSelectedItem().equals("Source")){ 
    int i=0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("source.txt");
        BufferedReader fd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String source=fd.readLine();
        while(source!=null){
            if(source.equals(addTextField.getText())){
                i++;break;
            }
        }
        fis.close();
        fd.close();
    } catch (Exception e5) {
    }  
    if(i==0){
        try {
            FileOutpuStream fis=new FileOutputStream("source.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter fd=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fis));
            fd.newLine();
            fd.write(addTextField.getText());
            fis.flush();
            fd.flush();
            fis.close();
            fd.close();                   
        } catch (Exception e1) {                           
        }                      
    }
    else{
        addLabel.setText("Already Exists");
    }
    addLabel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception e1) {  }` - first print out exception messages and stacktraces. If you get one and don't know what to make out of it add the stacktrace to your question (edit it).

Comment: Secondly, you seem to do I/O on the GUI-Thread. That's a "don't".

Comment: Fildor since I am a newbie i didn't know we shouldn't read and write through a GUI application.

Comment: That's why I wrote a comment about it :)

Comment: Now I'll kill my professor with why we shouldn't do IO with GUI.
He should have informed me. Now either he lives or me xD...

Comment: Wow, wow. I didn't say that. I said don't do it *on the GUI Thread*. It can lead to GUI freezes. Better do it in a BackgroundWorker or separate Thread or whatever your GUI toolkit gives you for doing "heavy lifting".

Answer (score 2):

```
String source=fd.readLine();
while(source!=null){
  if(source.equals(addTextField.getText())){
    i++;break;
  }
}
```

If source is not `null` and `source.equals(addTextField.getText())` is `false`, you loop forever.

Do the `readline()` in the loop.

```
String source = null;
while((source = fd.readLine()) != null){
  if(source.equals(addTextField.getText())){
    i++;
    break;
  }
}
```

Besides, you should avoid choking your exceptions :

```
catch (Exception e1) {                           
}
```

Print them or better log them :

```
catch (Exception e1) {                           
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 

catch (Exception e1) {                           
    LOGGER.error("Error during reading writing operation", e1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: By the way don t hesitate to accept my answer if it has solved your problem.